# Make print(df['ID'].value_counts()) to print all categories of column that contains 100 categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(df['ID'].value_counts())
```

output:

```
runfile('C:/del/untiwerwertled1.py', wdir='C:/del')
100    1
37     1
27     1
28     1
29     1
      ..
70     1
71     1
72     1
73     1
1      1
Name: ID, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

I need to print all categories (not only several first ones and several last ones as now). How to do that?

Comment: If you want to print all `100` of them `for c in df['ID'].unique(): print(c)` or set print limit in pandas.

Comment: pandas have the limitation of value show, so you can not show them all ~

Comment: in jupyter notebook, I would use `pd.options.display.max_rows = 100` after the `import` but not sure if it works within a script

Answer (score 1):

[Options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) in pandas handle this.

Just add:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows = 9999
```